# Write an empty MapReduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hortonworks-data-platform

I want to write an empty mapreduce job, Actually I mean a mapreduce job that doing nothing, Just has a Mapper, a Reducer and a main class. I want it for a test in hortonwoks sandbox 2.1.
this is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class MainClassName {

  public static class Map extends MapReduceBase 
    implements Mapper<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> 
  {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, 
      OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, 
      Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
    {
      output.collect(word, one);
    }
  }

  public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase 
    implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> 
  {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, 
      OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) 
      throws IOException 
    {
      int data = 0;
      }
      output.collect(key, new IntWritable(data));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
  {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(MainClassName.class);
    conf.setJobName("JobName");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
  }
}
```

Is it correct? 
but it gives me an error:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The type MainClassName.Map must implement the inherited abstract method Mapper.map(Text, Text, OutputCollector, Reporter)   MainClassName.java  /mainempty/src  line 14 Java Problem

And also I want to know which java files must be imported to run a simple job.
Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type arguments are a bit muddled. Your mapper is taking a `<LongWritable,Text>` pair, and outputting a `<Text,IntWritable>` pair. However your class declaration says:

```
implements Mapper<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text>
```

Which should read

```
implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable>
```

The rest looks OK.

Comment: Thank you very much #btbamcostello